# LoadString with nBufferMax equal 0

Tags: c++, winapi

i am working on making my applications international. After two days digging on msdn i came up with a test, which loads language-specific library containing resources. This is also my first attempt at loading library as a resource, loading strings from it and so on.

Next, according to msdn example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319071%28v=VS.85%29.aspx, i'm trying the LoadString.

Since string loading for entire application equals a lot of text copying, i thought i would use the - what i think is - memory efficient feature of LoadString, which is setting nBufferMax parameter to zero. According LoadString documentation, it should return a pointer to string resource. I thought i'd make a struct or a class of string pointers and do something along these lines (i extracted only the important bits):

```
wchar_t textBuf[SOMEVALUE]; // <-- this is how id DOES work
wchar_t *myString; // <-- this is how i would like it
HMODULE resContainer=LoadLibraryEx(L"MUILibENU.dll",NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
if(0!=resContainer){
  // this works OK
  int copied=LoadStringW(resContainer,IDS_APP_TITLE,textBuf,SOMEVALUE); 
  // this fails, also gives a warning at compile time about uninitialized variable used.
  int copied=LoadStringW(resContainer,IDS_APP_TITLE,myString,0);
}
```

As you can see i am trying to get myString to become a pointer to loaded resource library's string without actually copying anything.
My question is: am i misunderstanding msdn documentation? Can i or can i not get a pointer to the string directly within loaded library, and simply use it later, e.g. to show a messagebox, without actually copying anything? Until i unload said library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MSDN says:

> [...] If this parameter is 0, then lpBuffer receives a read-only pointer to the resource itself.

It means that a) the pointer must be of type `const wchar_t*`:

```
const wchar_t *myString;
```

and b) you must pass a pointer to the pointer and use an ugly cast:

```
int copied=LoadStringW(resContainer,IDS_APP_TITLE,(LPWSTR)&myString,0);
```

Comment: You've found an unusual MSDN page, [citation required]

Comment: i see, a type cast, i've actually tried with const wchar_t * but i somehow didn't think of casting it as shown. Maybe because i hate casts. It works though, despite being "ugly" :-)

Comment: @Kitet: unfortunately Windows API has many places where different functionality is squeezed within the same function. This leads to parameters having multiple roles depending on other parameters. So they are in fact treated more like `union`s, but they are not unions so you must do the cast. Besides the logic says that `LoadStringW` can't initialize your local variable unless you give a pointer to it... (It's C interface, remember?)

Comment: @HansPassant: It's written within the same page you linked from your answer.

Comment: Man that's weird, I just don't see it.  Please quote.

Comment: @ybungalobill: logic indeed says this, it just means i'm still not experienced enough. Working on it hard, though. I'm accepting your answer. And my test app also works on XP. I made a menu to choose language from, load appropriate library, populate class of pointers with its resources, then, if successful, reinitialize interface.

Comment: @HansPassant: it's in description of the function's last parameter, nBufferMax

Comment: I believe the page in question is just the LoadString MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647486(v=vs.85).aspx